# Numpy fromfunction returns error: Arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am implementing a neural network and have a problem with numpy.fromfunction function, which after running the following code:

```
def sigmoid(x, D=False):
    if not D:
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    else:
        return x * (1.0 - x)

class Neural_net:
    def __init__(self, n_input, n_hidden, n_output, transfer=sigmoid):
        self.n_input = n_input
        self.n_hidden = n_hidden
        self.n_output = n_output
        self.transfer = transfer
        self.layer1_weights = np.array([[random() for i in range(n_input)] for j in range(n_hidden)])
        self.layer2_weights = np.array([[random() for i in range(n_hidden)] for j in range(n_output)])
        self.layer2_weights = np.array([random() for j in range(n_hidden)])
        self.layer2_bias = np.array([random() for j in range(n_output)])

    def activation(self, weights, bias, layer):
        return np.sum(weights*layer) + bias

    def forward_propagation(self, input):
        input = np.array(input)
        *hidden_layer = np.fromfunction(lambda i: self.transfer(self.activation(self.layer1_weights[i],
             self.layer1_bias[i], input)), (self.n_hidden,))
        output_layer = np.fromfunction(lambda i: self.transfer(self.activation(self.layer2_weights[i],
             self.layer2_bias[i], hidden_layer)), (self.n_output,))
        return output_layer

my_net = Neural_net(2,2,2)
my_net.forward_propagation([1, 2])
```

returns IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type in line marked with asterisk. Does someone know what it might have been a problem?

Trace of error is here as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/BackPropagationNN/nn.py", line 74, in <module>
    print(my_net.forward_propagation([1, 2]))
  File "/home/david/BackPropagationNN/nn.py", line 25, in forward_propagation
    self.layer1_bias[i], input)), (self.n_hidden,))
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1809, in fromfunction
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/BackPropagationNN/nn.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    hidden_layer = np.fromfunction(lambda i:self.transfer(self.activation(self.layer1_weights[i], self.layer1_bias[i], input)), (self.n_hidden,))

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: It's hard to read the error line.  A full traceback might help.  So would breaking that line into pieces.  For example rewrite the `lambda` as a function.  I suspect the problem is with the `shape` that you pass, `(self.st_skriti,)`, but I can't say for sure.  BUT, you might be using `fromfunction` wrong.  The `lambda` is called just once on the whole array generated by `np.indices(shape)`.  It is not an iterator.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code enough to run an example? With what's given I can't reproduce your error. It would also be helpful if you gave the trace of the error.

Comment: I updated the post,  I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: That traceback doesn't distinguish between an error in `fromfunction` and one occurring in the lambda.  It's not in `self.activation`, but might be in the `layer1_weights[i]` indexing.  Rewrite the `lambda` to a function, and print(i)` as part of that.  You need to know exactly what `fromfunction` is passing to your lambda (or its replacement).

Answer (score 0):

Change the problem line to:

```
    def f1(i):
        print('i',i)
        a1 = self.layer1_weights[i]
        a2 = self.layer1_bias[i]
        temp = self.activation(a1, a2, input)
        return self.transfer(temp)
    hidden_layer = np.fromfunction(f1, (self.n_hidden,))
```

The run:

```
i [0. 1.]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack65584850.py", line 38, in <module>
    my_net.forward_propagation([1, 2])
  File "stack65584850.py", line 32, in forward_propagation
    hidden_layer = np.fromfunction(f1, (self.n_hidden,))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1809, in fromfunction
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "stack65584850.py", line 28, in f1
    a1 = self.layer1_weights[i]
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

See `fromfunction` passed `np.array([0., 1.])` to your `lambda`.  That is not a valid index.  `fromfunction` docs says the default dtype is float.

If I change the `fromfunction` dtype to int:

```
    hidden_layer = np.fromfunction(f1, (self.n_hidden,), dtype=int)
```

I get a

```
AttributeError: 'Neural_net' object has no attribute 'layer1_bias'
```

If I fudge that with

```
    self.layer1_bias = np.array([random() for j in range(n_input)])
```

`hidden_layer` runs, producing a 2 element array

[0.93625608 0.9462058 ]

The next `fromfunction` needs the same fix.

The key here is that `fromfunction` creates a `indices` array, here just `np.array([0,1])`, and passes that to the `lambda` - as a whole array.  It does not call the `lambda` 2 times with separate `i` values.  If you intend to iterate, `fromfunction` is the wrong thing to use.  Study its code if that doesn't make sense.

If you do want iteration on the `lambda i`, use (for now) a list comprehension.

Avoiding loops in `numpy` is laudable, but you have to use the right tools to do that.